# Can someone help me to finish this code with saving the readable dataframe as csv file? I could not save

Tags: dataframe, csv

I am trying to get the data in the dataframe as csv file, but I have always an error. I need a last code to convert the readable data content in python into saved csv file.

Code is here:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd`


browser=webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get("https://archive.doingbusiness.org/en/scores")

countries= WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='dftFrontiner']/div[3]/table"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")

df = pd.read_html(countries)

**df.to_csv('output'.csv, index=False)**

print(df)

time.sleep(2)

browser.quit()
```

Without the line written in bold, I can get the following output:

[          0                           1       2       3
0    Region                      Region  Region  Region
1       NaN         East Asia & Pacific    62.7    63.3
2       NaN       Europe & Central Asia    71.8    73.1
3       NaN   Latin America & Caribbean    58.8    59.1
4       NaN  Middle East & North Africa    58.4    60.2
..      ...                         ...     ...     ...
217     NaN                     Vietnam    68.6    69.8
218     NaN          West Bank and Gaza    59.7      60
219     NaN                 Yemen, Rep.    30.7    31.8
220     NaN                      Zambia    65.7    66.9
221     NaN                    Zimbabwe    50.5    54.5

When I add the bold line ( **df.to_csv('output'.csv, index=False)**), I could not save the file. However, I need this data in csv format. Please direct me how to write the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) returns a list of DataFrames. So, you need to slice before saving the `.csv`

Replace:

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

By this :

```
df[0].to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df[0])

          0                           1       2       3
0    Region                      Region  Region  Region
1       NaN         East Asia & Pacific    62.7    63.3
2       NaN       Europe & Central Asia    71.8    73.1
3       NaN   Latin America & Caribbean    58.8    59.1
4       NaN  Middle East & North Africa    58.4    60.2
..      ...                         ...     ...     ...
217     NaN                     Vietnam    68.6    69.8
218     NaN          West Bank and Gaza    59.7      60
219     NaN                 Yemen, Rep.    30.7    31.8
220     NaN                      Zambia    65.7    66.9
221     NaN                    Zimbabwe    50.5    54.5

[222 rows x 4 columns]
```

If you need a separated `.csv` for each group (Region & Economy), use this :

```
for g in df[0].ffill().groupby(0, sort=False):
    sub_df= g[1].reset_index(drop=True).iloc[1:, 1:]
    sub_df.to_csv(f"{g[0]}.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much 'abokey'. I can save now. However, I could not run the last code(for separated.csv) you have written in properly.

Comment: Glad it helped. I updated the `sub_df` bloc, you can run it now ;)

Comment: I cannot find a word for how I thank you. It works properly. Would you mind if I continued asking my questions about my current work? And can you explain the code you have written? I could not read what 3 line code meant. It worked but I want to understand also as a newbie.
Best Regards.